# Regular expression to match anything except a few specific strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to figure out how to write a regular expression in my MVC model to make sure the user does not type "USA" or "United States of America" ignoring case.  Right now I have this:

```
[RegularExpression("^(?i)([U][S][A])|(^United States of America)$", 
 ErrorMessage = "county, not country")]
```

It does exactly the opposite of what I want.  You can only type "USA" or "United States of America".  How do I "not" that expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

> [RegularExpression("^(?i)(?!USA$|United\sStates\sof\sAmerica$).*$",
>   ErrorMessage = "county, not country")]

Comment: I stuck dollar signs after each expression inside the parens, not it will allow "USAs" etc.